# postgres trigger not working properly - id argument not passed correctly to a new table

Tags: postgresql, triggers

for the following trigger in postges:

```
trigger vehicle_history
before update
 on public.vehicle
 for each row 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.log_vehicle_history()
```

with a function below:

```
function log_vehicle_history()
    returns trigger as 
$BODY$ BEGIN
IF NEW.lastupdated <> OLD.lastupdated THEN
INSERT INTO vehiclehistory(vehicle_id, event, datetime, latitude, longtitude, speed) 
VALUES(OLD.id, OLD.lastevent, OLD.lastupdated, OLD.latitude, OLD.longtitude, OLD.speed);
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ 
language PLPGSQL volatile
cost 100;
alter function log_vehicle_history() owner to postgres;
```

I get the following error:

```
2018-05-23 23:06:08.435 ERROR 12492 --- [       Thread-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  Details: Failing row contains **(null, 2018-05-23 13:07:53, 0, 34.221820000000001, 108.88527999999999, null, 8)**.
  Where: SQL statement "INSERT INTO vehiclehistory(vehicle_id, event, datetime, latitude, longtitude, speed) 
VALUES(OLD.id, OLD.lastevent, OLD.lastupdated, OLD.latitude, OLD.longtitude, OLD.speed)"
PL/pgSQL function log_vehicle_history() line 3 at SQL statement
```

For some reason within all the values only id is missing - **(null, 2018-05-23 13:07:53, 0, 34.221820000000001, 108.88527999999999, null, 8)**. Is id somekind of key word in postgres? How to fix that?

Tables are:

```
select
    v.datetime,
    v."event",
    v."id",
    v.latitude,
    v.longtitude,
    v.speed,
    v.vehicle_id
from
    public.vehiclehistory v;

select
    v.gpsstatus,
    v."id",
    v.imei,
    v.ip,
    v.lastevent,
    v.lastupdated,
    v.latitude,
    v.licenceplate,
    v.longtitude,
    v."name",
    v.port,
    v.speed,
    v.user_id
from
    vehicle v;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the table format for `public.vehicle`?  I can confirm `OLD.id` is not a problem in postgres, I use that all the time.

Comment: are you using some sort of application as the front end for inputting data? or are you performing direct queries into postgres.

Comment: @electricjelly @BShaps : thanks for the clues. Indeed I use Hibernate to insert the data into the table. It seems the id field is not from the vehicle table, but from vehicle history. While adding it with hibernate it works fine with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` in Spring Boot, but with the trigger function is does not work this way. How can I fix that? Some kind of sequence?

Comment: Hibernate uses select nextval ('hibernate_sequence') . Can it be used in the trigger somehow?

Comment: yes you can use something like `declare seq bigint :=nextval('hibernate_sequence');` put that in the beginning of the function, and call the value by inputting `seq` into where the value is needed